# SQL Server NOEXPAND with indexed view

Tags: sql-server

I've been researching a bit on the use of indexed views and the noexpand hint in SQL Server and needed some clarification. Let's assume for this example you have two situations.

1. An indexed view is created against a table which already has an index created for the underlying table
2. An indexed view is created against a table which does not have an index created for the underlying table.

If we omit the noexpand hint, will SQL Server utilize the the view index in either situation? Or is noexpand only applicable when the table has an index and there is a choice to be made?

Secondly, does this behavior vary between editions of SQL Server? Has anything changed in 2012?

Depending what message board, blog, or MSDN documentation you read, it's a little unclear.

Comment: `noexpand` has nothing to do with base table(s). It stops inlining view definition into the query being run. By default Sql Server merges views to query referencing them, effectively nullifying the purpose of indexed view, i.e. data is not being read from indexed view but rather from underlying objects. So, if you are not running enterprise edition, you need to specify `noexpand` hint.